# fmap (+1) $ read "[1]" gives error

Tags: haskell

When I type into the repl 
    fmap (+1) $ read "[1]" 
I would expect to get [2] but instead I get the error :

> No instance for (Functor f0) arising from a use of ‘it’

Unfortunately this doesn't help me. Could somebody explain to me what is wrong with this snipped of code.

Comment: Try explicitly giving it a type, e.g. `fmap (+1) $ read "[1]" :: [Int]`

Comment: Unrelatedly, you should pretty much never use `read`, because it makes your program crash if there's a parse error. Use something like `readMaybe` instead.

Comment: or just use `map`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just doesn't know what type read your value into. Help it by specifying the type explicitly:

```
fmap (+1) $ (read "[1]" :: [Int])
```